# error when compiling code with SSE

Tags: c++, cmake

When I tried to compile an open source code, it gave the following error message:

> `#error Please compile for the SSE2 instruction set or higher`
>   `#error Please compile for the SSE2 instruction set or higher`

Then I checked the CMakeLists.txt, as shown below:

```
SET(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -march=native -Wall -g")
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -march=native -Wall  -g -O3")
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -march=native -std=c++11")
```

I guess something gets wrong here, could anyone help?

My CPU is intel 7700K

Comment: I assume you are using gcc and compiling a 32 bit application.

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.1/gcc/i386-and-x86_002d64-Options.html

Comment: You can try adding `-msse2` to your flags. Although I would expect -march=native to add sse2 support if your cpu has it.

Comment: The `#error` is a preprocessor macro. While it likely is triggered by `#ifndef __SSE2__` (or equivalent), it might be prudent to check in the code which condition in the preprocessor is actually triggering it.